# How to modify data-list element or alternative

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, html-datalist

I am working on an autocomplete text input by testing for string similarity, rather than checking for perfect character matches. This way, a `dropdown` like a `datalists` would still present the user with suggestions even if they accidentally add an extra character or spell their desired input wrong.

I have a working Javascript file that can compare the string input from an HTML text input to all the strings in a JSON file that holds about 700 school names as strings. The Javascript file then formats the HTML and passes the 10 most similar strings into an unordered list(for debugging) and into a data-list (where the user will be able to pick their correct answer).

However, `datalists` seem to have built-in autocomplete that check for identical groups of characters and the `datalists` will intelligently remove suggestions if the inputted string does not exist within the suggestion.

```
<input 
    type ="text" 
    id="search" 
    list="hsDropdown" 
    class ="form-control form-control-lg"
    placeholder="High School Name"
    autocomplete="off"
    autofocus = "false"
/>

<hr/>

<p id="word"></p>
<datalist id ="hsDropdown"></datalist>
<ul id ="list"></ul>

</main>

<script src="js/script.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/ukkonen/index.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
```

The options within the `datalist` in my HTML are properly populated by my script.js with the most similar strings, but I need to find a way to override the property of the `datalist` tag that causes results with nonperfect matches to not appear, or

I would need to find an alternative way to make a `dropdown` list appear from a `textbox` that is not limited to hard auto-correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the **[select2](https://github.com/select2)** jQuery plugin and the Fuzzy search issue opened [there](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4837)

[As per requestor](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4837#issuecomment-418021718), he has implemented the `fuzzy_match` function and embedded it into the plugin as the following:

> I've also a function called matcher, which looks something like:

```
function matcher(term, text){
    if(term.term === undefined){
        return {text: text, score: 1};
    }
    var match = fuzzy_match(term.term, text.text);
    return (match[0])?{text: text, score: match[1]}:false;
}
```

> I also have a sorter, which sorts the matched elements, (so matching elements come at top)

```
function sorter(data) {
    return data.filter(function(item) {
        return !!item;
    }).sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score)
          .map(item => item.text);
}
```

> And whenever we're invoking a select2 on a element, we're passing this matcher as a matcher option, and sorter as sorter option, which looks something like:

```
$("#element").select2({
  placeholder: 'select a name',
  matcher,
  sorter
})
```

[Here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4837#issuecomment-303604019) is the `fuzzy_match` function code provided:

```js
/**
 *
 * @param pattern
 * @param str
 * @returns {[boolean,score,formatted]}
 */
function fuzzy_match(pattern, str) {

 // Score consts
 var adjacency_bonus = 55;                // bonus for adjacent matches
 var separator_bonus = 10;               // bonus if match occurs after a separator
 var camel_bonus = 10;                   // bonus if match is uppercase and prev is lower
 var leading_letter_penalty = -3;        // penalty applied for every letter in str before the first match
 var max_leading_letter_penalty = -9;    // maximum penalty for leading letters
 var unmatched_letter_penalty = -1;      // penalty for every letter that doesn't matter

 // Loop variables
 var score = 0;
 var patternIdx = 0;
 var patternLength = pattern.length;
 var strIdx = 0;
 var strLength = str.length;
 var prevMatched = false;
 var prevLower = false;
 var prevSeparator = true;       // true so if first letter match gets separator bonus

 // Use "best" matched letter if multiple string letters match the pattern
 var bestLetter = null;
 var bestLower = null;
 var bestLetterIdx = null;
 var bestLetterScore = 0;

 var matchedIndices = [];

 // Loop over strings
 while (strIdx != strLength) {
  var patternChar = patternIdx != patternLength ? pattern.charAt(patternIdx) : null;
  var strChar = str.charAt(strIdx);

  var patternLower = patternChar != null ? patternChar.toLowerCase() : null;
  var strLower = strChar.toLowerCase();
  var strUpper = strChar.toUpperCase();

  var nextMatch = patternChar && patternLower == strLower;
  var rematch = bestLetter && bestLower == strLower;

  var advanced = nextMatch && bestLetter;
  var patternRepeat = bestLetter && patternChar && bestLower == patternLower;
  if (advanced || patternRepeat) {
   score += bestLetterScore;
   matchedIndices.push(bestLetterIdx);
   bestLetter = null;
   bestLower = null;
   bestLetterIdx = null;
   bestLetterScore = 0;
  }

  if (nextMatch || rematch) {
   var newScore = 0;

   // Apply penalty for each letter before the first pattern match
   // Note: std::max because penalties are negative values. So max is smallest penalty.
   if (patternIdx == 0) {
    var penalty = Math.max(strIdx * leading_letter_penalty, max_leading_letter_penalty);
    score += penalty;
   }

   // Apply bonus for consecutive bonuses
   if (prevMatched)
    newScore += adjacency_bonus;

   // Apply bonus for matches after a separator
   if (prevSeparator)
    newScore += separator_bonus;

   // Apply bonus across camel case boundaries. Includes "clever" isLetter check.
   if (prevLower && strChar == strUpper && strLower != strUpper)
    newScore += camel_bonus;

   // Update patter index IFF the next pattern letter was matched
   if (nextMatch)
    ++patternIdx;

   // Update best letter in str which may be for a "next" letter or a "rematch"
   if (newScore >= bestLetterScore) {

    // Apply penalty for now skipped letter
    if (bestLetter != null)
     score += unmatched_letter_penalty;

    bestLetter = strChar;
    bestLower = bestLetter.toLowerCase();
    bestLetterIdx = strIdx;
    bestLetterScore = newScore;
   }

   prevMatched = true;
  }
  else {
   // Append unmatch characters
   formattedStr += strChar;

   score += unmatched_letter_penalty;
   prevMatched = false;
  }

  // Includes "clever" isLetter check.
  prevLower = strChar == strLower && strLower != strUpper;
  prevSeparator = strChar == '_' || strChar == ' ';

  ++strIdx;
 }

 // Apply score for last match
 if (bestLetter) {
  score += bestLetterScore;
  matchedIndices.push(bestLetterIdx);
 }

 // Finish out formatted string after last pattern matched
 // Build formated string based on matched letters
 var formattedStr = "";
 var lastIdx = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < matchedIndices.length; ++i) {
  var idx = matchedIndices[i];
  formattedStr += str.substr(lastIdx, idx - lastIdx) + "<b>" + str.charAt(idx) + "</b>";
  lastIdx = idx + 1;
 }
 formattedStr += str.substr(lastIdx, str.length - lastIdx);

 var matched = patternIdx == patternLength;
 return [matched, score, formattedStr];
}
```